# dependent query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables like **A,B,C** and here what my requirement is

- in **A table** having two foreign key from B and C table and
- I want if b_id is not null then get data from the **B table**
- else if c_id is not null then get data from the **C table**.

B and C Tables having the three to four colums. Please see the following structure.

```
A Table
a_id(pk) |  b_id(fk) | C_id(fk)

1        |    null   |         1
2        |       2   |      null
```

For that above requirement i tried but not achieve my goal. please anybody to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: wt u trying to select ?

Comment: @BhavinRana: what does "`wt u`" mean? (Sorry for asking, but English is not my native language)

Comment: i'd assume it just means `what you` or he just forgot another `f` :DDD

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question you want to do a left join on tables B and C

```
Select B.*, C.*
From table_A A left join Table_B B on A.B_Id=B.Id
left join Table_C C on A.C_Id = C.Id
```

Comment: this will get all the data from `B` and `C` regardless of whether it contains `NULL` or not

Comment: you are right, now that the OP has better explained the problem my solution is not the one he need

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean to have `left joins` on table B and C and `COALESCE` some value *(or values? you did not provide any column list or what your desired output is so I assume there is just one content containing column in table B as well as in C)*

For selecting from one column in those tables I would do the following

```
SELECT
        COALESCE(B.yourcontentcolumn, C.yourcontentcolumn, <defaultvalueifnull>)
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.b_id
    LEFT JOIN C ON C.id = A.c_id
```